# Для заданного y найти значения x

Tags: машинное-обучение, scikit-learn, scipy

Помогите, пожалуйста, найти подход к решению следующей задачи:

Пусть есть матрица `X = (x1,…,xn)`, состоящая из временных рядов `xi` и вектор `y`. Суть задачи в том, чтобы научиться косвенно управлять парамeтром `y` с помощью изменения параметров `xi`-x.

1. Для предсказания значений из `y` натренируем какую-л. модель, для интерпретируемости возьмем линейную регрессию. Получим `y = f(X)`.
2. Нужно для любого произвольного значения `y_0` найти `Х_0`, при котором достигается это значение.

Первая мысль была перебирать значения для X, вторая мысль взять коэф. лин рег-ии и решить систему уравнений, получив искомый `x_0`. Но в общем, как я понимаю, нужно решить уравнение `F(X) - y_0 = 0`, но никак не могу подступиться к решению. Подскажите, какие существуют способы решения такого рода задач? Возможно здесь имеет место применение какого-л. метода из пакета scipy.optimize, просветите меня, пожалуйста.

Прилагаю пример имеющихся данных.

```
d = pd.DataFrame({'x1': [70, 75, 80, 65, 60, 55, 105, 55], 'x2': [85.2, 92.9, 91.0, 85.8, 78.0, 80.0, 75.0, 124.0],
                  'x3': [113, 114, 139, 97, 107, 122, 60, 72], 'x4': [39, 62, 72, 17, 14, 21, 12, 35],
                  'y': [136, 105, 108, 98, 68, 93, 91, 115]})
d.index.name = 'time'
```

Comment: Но ведь преобразование `x -> y` может быть и не взаимо-однозначным. То есть одному `y` может соответствовать и несколько `x`. Вообще вам бы картинки какие нарисовать, так вот на пальцах задача не очень понятная. А вообще, если у вас линейная регрессия, то есть грубо говоря `y = a * x + b`, то у вас же есть коэффициенты `a` и `b`, вы можете вычислить `x = (y - b) / a`. Главное, чтобы `a` не было равно `0`.

Comment: Ну да, если лин.рег я могу систему уравнений решить и получить (х1,..,хn). 
А если это более сложная модель.. Вообще в задаче мне нужно управлять параметром y косвенно через xi-e, т.е. найти f(x)=y и для любого заданного y находить xi-e, при которых это значение достигается. Вот не знаю, как подступиться. И еще чтоб более менее интерпретируемо было.

Comment: Улучшайте вопрос - добавьте пример данных, как-то схематически нарисуйте проблему. Тогда всем проще будет, и вам в том числе. Вообще говоря, линейная регрессия довольно хорошо интерпретируема. Другое дело, что да - коэффициентов там целый вектор. Вам нужно из имеющихся уже `Y` найти `X` или для произвольного? Повторюсь - нужны примеры, нужны схемы какие-то, так задача с трудом понятна. Если что-то похожее на уже имеющееся, то просто ищете в ваших `Y` наиболее близкое значение к конкретному `y` и берёте `x`-ы соответствующие. А вот если что-то между значениями, то нужно думать уже.

Comment: Да, для произвольного Y, не получится просто смотреть на имеющиеся Y.

Comment: Я только не пойму, как вы собираетесь мерить близость ответа к искомому. Если у вас нет функции, которой можно это проверить. А, или построенной регрессией проверять... Ну тогда вполне может `scipy.optimize` помочь собственно решить. Если там все зависимости простые, я бы вообще взял ваши `x` по одному и построил регрессию `y -> x` для этой колонки. И так для каждой из колонок `x`. Ну и потом можно подставлять в модели для каждой из колонок ваш новый `y` и получать для каждой из колонок значение `x`. Повторюсь - если бы вы привели какой-то пример данных, разговаривать было бы гораздо проще.

Comment: Немного подкорректировала вопрос. Да, проверять с помощью регрессии. Я думала над вашим предложением построить регрессии по отдельности, но была мысль, вдруг на параметр `y` влияет композиция из параметров `xi`..

Comment: Да, если сложно как-то влияет композиция, то это будет решение системы уравнений, наверное. Я в уравнениях не силён. )  Ну вы проверьте, может у вас там линейные зависимости хотя бы для части столбцов. Тогда можно найти значения для этих столбцов, а дальше уже с помощью их значений искать остальные.

Comment: Что касается приложенных данных, то `y` у вас сильно коррелирует только с `x2` и `x4`, а остальные столбцы уже между собой коррелируют дальше. Посмотрите `d.corr()` для начала. Если возьмёте линейную регрессию, она примерно тоже самое покажет.

Comment: Да-да, я для полной картины скинула данные, там в принципе только 3 столбца из 12-ти коррелируют хоть как-то с `y`..

Answer (score 2):

Давайте подумаем. Если вы говорите *о временном ряде  и о предсказании значения*, то это означает, что на исторических данных вы строите модель -  любую, линейную, нелинейную регрессии, ARIMA, Хольта-Винтерса и пр. а потом продолжаете эту модель на будущие периоды. Это и есть ваше предсказание. В такой постановке `"для любого произвольного значения y_0 найти Х_0, при котором достигается это значение"` означает, что такое Х может быть только в "будущем". Имея модель, и подставляя в нее последовательно "будущие" значения тиков времени вы соответственно и делаете предсказания значения у.  До тех пор пока не найдете либо заданное Y, либо число задвно близкое к Y, либо.... никогда не найдете такого Y, например, потому что вышли из зоны адекватности прогноза. При этом не надо "решать" уравнение, надо просто перебирать тики времени.

Вот если бы вы рассматривали не временной ряд, а обычную регрессионную модель, не зависящую от времени, вот в такой постановке под термином "предсказание" также  понимают задачу нахождения значений Y при значении Х, которого не было в обучающей выборке.  И тогда - получив ур-ние регрессии и ее коэффициенты - к задаче F(X) - y_0 = 0. Такие задачи относительно просто решаются хорошо известными численными методами, часто - простейшими, из вузовской программы.

Пока приал, вы там пример подкинули. Но из него не ясно, у вас  временнОй ряд или "чистая" регрессия? Зависит-ли значение Y от времени или только от значений ваших x1....x2. Это невозможно статистически понять, это определяется только семантически из вашей задачи. Но если - как мне кажется -  зависимости от времени как такового нет (просто последовательность замерянных в последовательные моменты времени данных -  это НЕ временной ряд) -  то задача сводиться к многомерной регрессии и второму из описанных выше подходов в чистом виде, с которым  прекрасно умеют справляться численные методы.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! Да, кстати забыла упомянуть, ‘y’ зависит так же и от времени..

Comment: Кстати, да, если докинуть `time` в фичи и сделать `corr`, то выяснится, что у `y` сильная отрицательная корреляция с `time`. Это временной ряд и правда, похоже. Но в остальном картина не сильно меняется.

Comment: Тогда в первую очередь надо проверить -  от времени зависит y, или от времени зависят х1,...x4, а уже через них происходит влияние на y.